# CorePlot support for arm64?

Tags: ios, core-plot, xcode5.1

In Core-plot 1.4, I can use the pre-built Binaries/iOS/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a library in my iOS app, but only if I delete "arm64"  as a valid architecture in BuildSettings/ValidArchitecture script.

Can I rebuild this library to include arm64 using Source/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj, setting its BuildSetting/Architecture to arm64?

The same question applies to CorePlot1.5.1. In 1.5.1, where can I easily find the CorePlotHeaders folder, which conveniently is Binaries/iOS/ in 1.4.

When I build, I get the Debug products, but do not see Release products in places where Build Settings says they should be. What am I (still new'ish to Xcode5) missing?

Why would I want to include CorePlot as a dependent item, rather than simply include its static library in my Xcode project app? The latter is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

1. *Can I rebuild this library to include arm64 using Source/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj, setting its BuildSetting/Architecture to arm64?*

   **Yes. Build the "Universal Library" target to make a complete release binary with both device and simulator code.**
2. *The same question applies to CorePlot1.5.1. In 1.5.1, where can I easily find the CorePlotHeaders folder, which conveniently is Binaries/iOS/ in 1.4.*

   **The headers are in the same place in the 1.5 and 1.5.1 release folders, too.**
3. *When I build, I get the Debug products, but do not see Release products in places where Build Settings says they should be. What am I (still new'ish to Xcode5) missing?*

   **This is determined by the selected "scheme". By default, building or running makes a debug version while profiling or archiving makes a release version.**
4. *Why would I want to include CorePlot as a dependent item, rather than simply include its static library in my Xcode project app?*

   **You would use the dependent library build if you were keeping up with the latest code from Github or using your own private fork. You can always build a static library from source (see question #1, above), but if the Core Plot code is changing often, its easier to include the project directly.**

Comment: i think this is true answer but i m getting error and it says:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_vDSP_maxvD", referenced from:
      -[CPTPlot plotRangeForField:] in libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)
  "_vDSP_minvD", referenced from:
      -[CPTPlot plotRangeForField:] in libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)
Do you have an idea what is this? i carefully followed your answer.

Comment: Recent versions of Core Plot (after 1.5.1) require the Accelerate framework on iOS.

Comment: thank you very much. It worked. I wish this error was more clear. I didn't even think about this framework.